# Can I view a specific chapter in a manual?

Tags: bash, man

Can I view a specific chapter in a manual?

I tried `man socket(2)` in WSL Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial).

This is after I got a recommendation to see chapter 2 in a man of the `socket` utility.

Comment: `See the socket(2) manual`.

Comment: "See the socket(2) manual."

Comment: I tried `man socket(2)` not `man socket 2` as seen from `history`. Edited and sorry !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `man <section_number> <package_name>`, i.e.  `man 2 socket`

Or `man <package_name>.<section_number>`, i.e. `man socket.2`.

From `man man`:

> man man.7
>
> Display the manual page for macro package man from section 7.

And also from `man man`:

> man [[section] page[.section] ...]

Answer (score 1):

Section 2 is the section that deals with system calls. To read a man page in that section you append a .2 to the system call. So the socket(2) manual is found by entering:

```
man socket.2
```

See also:

```
$ man man
```

Comment: `man 2 socket` works the same too.